# Как заменить строки с 0 на значения из строки выше с о значением !=0?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

Создают новый столбец, в нем полявляются нужные мне значения через огромные пропуски `NaN`.
Удаляю пропуски первой строкой кодa - меняю их на 0. Затем, хочу заменить значения 0 на те, которые были так сказать до этого числом - через проверку по условию пытаюсь копировать, но так в лоб не копируются значения.

Как сделать правильно?

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df.loc[df['mes'] == 0, 'mes'] = df['mes'].shift(1)
```

```
44.7
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
45.2
0
0
0
0
```

Итог:

```
44.7
44.7
44.7
44.7
44.7
44.7
44.7
44.7
44.7
45.2
45.2
45.2
45.2
45.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо `df.fillna(0, inplace=True)`  воспользуйтесь методом [Series.ffill()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
df['mes'] = df['mes'].ffill()
```